# How to not loop through an object

Tags: php

I have an object that looks like this

```
{
    "Product_1": {
        "name": "Product 1",
        "price": "300"
    },
    "Product_2": {
        "name": "Product 2",
        "price": "300"
    },
    "Product_3": {
        "name": "Product 3",
        "price": "300"
    },
}
```

What I would like to know is. Is it possible to grab the keys for example: `Product_1`, `Product_2` without having to loop through it?

Comment: What do You mean by "grab the keys"? How are You doing it now and how do You want to improve it? What are You trying to achieve?

Comment: @MáriusRak - At the moment I'm looping through it, but I'm doing multiple loops, so I was hoping that there was a way to not have to do so many loops and only grab the key that I need

Comment: Do you want to get all the keys, a specific key, or the object subset of a key?

Comment: @PeterSH - I want to get all the keys

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can using the [array_keys](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) method like this:

```
$json = '{
    "Product_1": {
        "name": "Product 1",
        "price": "300"
    },
    "Product_2": {
        "name": "Product 2",
        "price": "300"
    },
    "Product_3": {
        "name": "Product 3",
        "price": "300"
    }
}';

$array = json_decode($json, JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY);

$keys = array_keys($array);
```

Comment: Why would you make a json from it?

Comment: @MáriusRak That is the opposite. It is JSON format and `json_decode` with  `JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY` will, I assume, tranform the JSON data into an array instead of an object

Comment: @Claudio - I will give it a shot

Answer (score 0):

You can get all keys of the object simply by call the function `get_object_vars()`